# Javascript: how to set intervals with a variable or run code once?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, web, setinterval

I have a problem with javascript because I want to run code in a function once until a interval is again over. So I have read about a possibilty to use an boolean to control it but without intervals and it is still calling the updatePosition() function over and over without stopping.
Simplyfied I have code in this structure:

```
var runPerm = false;
function start() {
    setInterval(setPerm, 2000);
    setInterval(function() {
        new updatePosition()
    }, 2000);
}
function setPerm() {
    runPerm = true;
}
function updatePosition() {
    if (runPerm == true) {
        //some code that I want to run once.
        runPerm = false;
    }
}
```

Has someone an idea to solve the problem?
(A full code: http://pastebin.com/iSFHjct3 )

Comment: If you only want to run the code once, why are you updating `runPerm=true` once every 2000 ms ? Why are you using the `new` keyword here ? How about you try to tell us what you're trying to do rather than asking about this specific code.

Comment: @naomik Sorry, to make this more clearly: I want only to run updatePosition() once EVERY 2000 ms.     So my question is more like: how can I get this?   Actually you can ignore what I putted in my piece of code, it is not correctly to use 'new', I had to try something so this was over from testing. But more important is the question in this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

```
var runPerm = false;
function start() {
    setInterval(setPerm, 2000);
    setTimeout(updatePosition, 2000);
}
```